# Let V be an inner product space.Then for x,y,z belongs to V and belongs to field,F,the following statements are true.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

(a) $\langle x,y+z\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle+\langle x,z\rangle$.

(b) $\langle x,cy\rangle =\bar c\langle x,y\rangle$.

(c) $\langle x,0\rangle = \langle 0,x\rangle =0$.

(d) $\langle x,x\rangle=0$ iff $x=0$.

(e) If $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,z\rangle$ for all $x$ belongs to $V$, then $y=z$.

$PROOF$(a): $\Longrightarrow$ We have, $\langle x,y+z\rangle=\overline{\langle y+z,x\rangle} = \overline{\langle y,x\rangle} + \overline{\langle z,x\rangle} = \langle x,y\rangle+\langle x,z\rangle$.

By using the conjugation criteria for inner product space i've also proved (b).But,i'm not getting how to  proceed for (c),(d) &(e).

I need some hint.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your definition of an inner product?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:It's a theorem.Everything i've used here is definition of Inner product on an arbitrary vector space V(F).

Comment: I cleaned up a lot of your MathJax code.  Can you fix the rest of it? $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy:I'll try

Comment: @PKStyles : Note that the "equals" signs should be inside the MathJax environment. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy>Thanks!! I'm still learning{:-->)-<--<

Comment: I've also done (c)

Comment: completed (d) also

Comment: Please help in (e)

Comment: @PKStyles I am very confused by your answer.  How can the definition of an inner product be a theorem?  I believe that the things you used are from the definition of an inner product, but I still don't know *what that definition is*, so I *don't know what I'm allowed to use*.  Perhaps now you understand why I'm asking.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:No,no this question is a theorem.here is the definition:Let V be a vector space over F.An inner product on V is a function that assigns,to every ordered pair of vectors x and y in ,a scalar in F,denoted <x,y>,such that for all x,y,z in V and all c in F,the following holds:(a)<x+z,y>=<x,y>+<z,y>;(b)<cx,y>=c<x,y>;(c)complex conjugate of <x,y>=<y,x>.(d)<x,x>>0 if x not equal to 0.I hope you wanted to know this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,z\rangle$ for every $x \in V$, then we can say that 
$$
\langle x,y-z \rangle = 0
$$
(again, for every $x \in V$).  Now, what happens if we let $x = y-z$?

Comment: :Now i got it.Thanks!!